# Scoring function that penalizes negative answers

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem with `Positive` and `Negative` asnwers and I want to assign a score ranging from `0` to `1`. I want I also want is to penalize the `Negative` answers. The more the worst. For example, the `Case 1` has `5 Positive` and `3 Negative` answers. How can I calculate its score? Can someone suggest to me an algorithm to look for?

**EDIT**

As correctly Bill O'Haran mentioned in the comments, what I am looking for is a sort of scoring function that calculates a very bad score once negative answers occur and also take into consideration the amount of negative answers. Moreover, the function should not award with a high score the positive answers.

Comment: You might want to provide more context. As it is, I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I will give an example. Assume you have an online shop and 5 persons have voted it as positive and 3 as negative. You would like to come up with a final score between 0 and 1 and assign that score to the online shop. But you want penalize higher the Negative reviews and also penalize their amount. It's different to have 1 Negative review than 3. Do I make things more clear right now?

Comment: So you are looking for a sort of scoring function that would tend to give very bad grades once negative answers occur but would not neccessarily award high scores to many positive answers? If that is right, please edit your question so you may receive relevant answers.

Comment: Anyone to give some help here?

Comment: It is a very open question (which might cause it to be put on hold). I have a proposition that is quite simple: if $n-1$ negative answers have already been registered and a new one arrives. You substract (or set to $0$ if you get a result $<0$) a constant $c$ to your score (where you choose $c$ according to your needs, it must be quite large $\approx \frac{1}{4}$ or so to make the score drop sensibly). If you have $p-1$ positive answers registered and a new one arrives, you add $\frac{1}{2^{p+1}}$ to the score. The initial score is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Assume that I have no new answers than $$score = 1/2-1/4(n) + \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}$$

Comment: See [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting.

Comment: Not exactly the whole "set to $0$ if you get a result $<0$" makes it difficult to express simply. Also, it is not $ \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}$ alone but $\sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{1}{2^{i+1}}$ otherwise the score decreases as positive answers are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up my proposition:

- initialize the score as $s_0=\frac{1}{2}$
- if a new positive answer (the $p$-th one) occurs, the adjusted score is $c_{k+1}(P) = c_{k}+\frac{1}{2^{p+1}}$
- if a new negative answer (the $n$-th one) occurs, the adjusted score is $c_{k+1}(N) = \max (c_{k}-c, 0)$ where $c$ has been defined in advance.

This way, negative answers will yield a $0$ within at most $\lceil \frac{1}{c}\rceil$ occurences. Also, positive answers allow to get as close to a perfect score as possible but $1$ is not reachable.

Comment: Just a small question: Why the score will not reach `1`? Assume that we have only 2 `Positive` answers and 0 `Negative`. Than the score will be $score = s_{0} + \sum_{i=0}^1 \frac{1}{2^{i+1}}=1.25$

Comment: The sum starts at $i=1$ and ends at $2$. It will never reach $1$ because the maximal sum (with an infinite amount of positive answers and no negative answers) is $s_0+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$. An infinite amount of positive answers is not possible in practise so $1$ is never reached.